# If $c$ is a real number, then $\sum_{x\in X} cf(x)$ is absolutely convergent, and $ \sum_{x\in X} cf(x) = c\sum_{x\in X} f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Let $X$ be an arbitrary set (possibly uncountable), and let $f:X → R$ and $g: X → R$ be functions such that the series $\sum_{x∈X} f(x)$ and $\sum_{x∈X} g(x)$  are both absolutely convergent.
>
> If $c$ is a real number, then $\sum_{x\in X} cf(x)$ is absolutely convergent,
> and $$ \sum_{x\in X} cf(x) = c\sum_{x\in X} f(x)$$

I know that this is true if the $X$ is finite. Now I want to tackle the countable and uncountable cases.

If it is countable than by definition there exists some $g:N\to X$ such that $\sum_{x\in X}cf(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}cf(g(n))$ which is absolutely convergent.
Which means that partial sums $S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N}cf(g(n)$ are absolutely convergent by definition $2$. Which means (by definition $1$) that $\sum_{x \in A}cf(x)$ is absolutely convergent where $A$ is a finite subset of $X$. From which since $A$ is finite I get $\sum_{x \in A}cf(x) = c\sum_{x \in A}f(x)$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}cf(g(n)) = c\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(g(n))= c\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$.

Is this proof true? Here I used the following definitions:
Definition $1$

> Let $X$ be a finite set
> with $n$ elements (where $n ∈ N$), and let $f: X → R$ be a function from $X$
> to the real numbers (i.e., $f$ assigns a real number $f(x)$ to each element $x$
> of $X$). Then we can define the finite $\sum_{x∈X} f(x)$ as follows. We first select any bijection $g$ from {$i ∈ N : 1 ≤ i ≤ n$} to $X$; such a bijection
> exists since $X$ is assumed to have $n$ elements. We then define
> $$ \sum_{x\in X} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(g(i)) $$

Definition $2$

> Let $\sum^∞_{n=m} a_n$ be a formal infinite series. For any integer $N ≥ m$, we define the $N$-th partial sum $S_N$ of this series to be $S_N := \sum_{n=m}^{N} a_n$; of course, $S_N$ is a real number.
> If the sequence $(S_N)^{∞}_{N=m}$ converges to some limit $L$ as $N → ∞$, then
> we say that the infinite series $\sum^∞_{n=m} a_n$ is convergent, and converges
> to $L$.

If $X$ is uncountable then using the fact that when $\sum_{x∈X} f(x)$ are absolutely convergent then we can write it as $$ \sum_{x∈X} f(x) = \sum_{x∈X:f(x) \not=0} f(x) $$
This in combination with the fact that {$x∈X:f(x) \not=0$} is at most countable reduces this case to the previous two ones, so the statment holds here too.

Comment: There really isn't much of a notion of an uncountable sum of positive terms.  Any such sum diverges  (as at least one of the intervals $\left[1,\infty\right), \left\{\left[\frac 1{n+1},\frac 1n \right)\right\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ must contain infinitely many of your terms).

Comment: @lulu Isn't this simply the proof that $\sum_{x\in X} f(x)$ absolutely convergent implies $\{x \in X : f(x) \neq 0\}$ is at most countable (which OP uses in the last paragraph)?  Is there something greater you are implying that I'm just missing?

Comment: @BrianMoehring  No...I;'m just saying that the uncountable case immediately reduces to the countable one.

Comment: But how does one interpret a sum indexed by an uncountable set?

Comment: If $X$ is uncountable, then $$\sum_{x\in X}f(x) = \sup\left\{\sum_{x\in F}f(x) : F\subset X, F \text{ finite}\right\}. $$

Comment: @Math1000 What you have written is correct for  $f \geq 0$ but not in  general. If $f(0)=1, f(1)=-1$ and $f(x)=0$ for all other real numbers $x$ then LHS is $0$ and RHS is $1$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Yes, I meant for a function $f:X\to [0,\infty]$. Sorry for excluding that from the assumptions.